# Set object properties to those of parent element

Tags: angular

I am using tabs from angular material. I simplified the code as much as I could. Each mat-tab has its own label and each tab also contains an exampleComponent. Each example Component is supposed to output the label of the mat-tab that contains that component.

matTabsComponent.html:

```html
<mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab label="dog">
        <exampleComponent></exampleComponent>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="cat">
        <exampleComponent></exampleComponent>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="bunny">
        <exampleComponent></exampleComponent>
</mat-tab-group>
```

exampleComponent.html:

```html
<p> {{label}} works! </p>
```

ExampleComponent.ts:

```js
export class exampleComponent implements OnInit {

  label: string;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    /*pseudocode:
    this.label = getParentElement.getAttribute("label") */
  }
}
```

Comment: User `@Input()` on the `ExampleComponent`'s label property and pass the label down to the `ExampleComponent`

Comment: Here's what I did:
@Input('label') label: string;
ngOnInit() { console.log(this.label) .
It outputs 'unidentified' 3 times to the console

Comment: Did you pass down the label text to the exampleComponent in the template? `<exampleComponent label="dog"></exampleComponent>`

Comment: Event better is if you have the labels in an array in the matTabsComponent.ts file and loop through the array in the template to build the tabs.

Comment: Tried both. Your first suggestion still outputs "undefined" 3 times and the loop through an array outputs the first label property (in this case "dog") 3 times

Comment: can you put together a stackblitz recreating the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

matTabsComponent.ts:

```
export class matTabsComponent{

labels=['dog','cat','bunny'];

}
```

matTabsComponent.html:

```
<mat-tab-group>

<ng-container *ngFor="let label of labels">
<mat-tab label="{{label}}">

<exampleComponent [label]="label"></exampleComponent>

</mat-tab>
<ng-container>
</mat-tab-group>
```

exampleComponent.html:

```
<p> {{label}} works! </p>
```

exampleComponent.ts:

```
export class exampleComponent implements OnInit {

 @Input label?: string;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.label);
  }
}
```